# Neo4j Cypher - delete array property at a given index

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How do I remove an element in a property array using Cypher?

For example, assuming `user` is set in a query already, I know you can use `REMOVE` to remove a property, e.g

```
REMOVE user.favouriteColours
```

But if this was an array, how can I remove the first element?

```
REMOVE user.favouriteColours[0]
```

or

```
REMOVE user.favouriteColours.0
```

doesn’t work and I can’t seem to see anything on Google or the docs.

Thanks

Edit:

I should mention, I know you can RETURN with `user.favouriteColours[0]` to get the first element, but removing doesn’t work

Answer (score 3):

To remove the first element of an array you can use the `tail` function:

```
MATCH (user:User {id:123})
SET user.favouriteColors = tail(user.favouriteColors)
```

If you need to solve this more generically by removing the n-th element of an array;

```
MATCH (user:User {id:123})
SET user.favouriteColors = user.favouriteColors[0..n] +
    user.favouriteColors[n+1..length(user.favouriteColors)]
```

Comment: Or use `MATCH (user:User {id:123})
SET user.favouriteColors = user.favouriteColors[1..]`

Comment: Worth saying though that the array indexes start at 1 (which Michaels comment includes but one could miss as an ovesight) - **not** at 0 as many other environments would.